# Web forms and URL rewriting: Hide ID, show name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, url-routing

I am working with URL rewriting, and have some issues. I want my url to be like this:

```
www.domain.com/product/myproduct
```

But I also want to be able to retrieve the ID of the product, without accessing the database.  I thought about having a URL like:

```
www.domain.com/product/myproduct/1
```

or

```
www.domain.com/product/1-myproduct
```

But if I could hide the ID it would be better.

So, how do I do it the simplest way?

Currently my Global.asax has the following route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Produkt visning",
                        "legetoej/{Categoryname}/{SubCategoryname}/{ProductName}",
                        "~/SingleProduct.aspx");
```

And when I retrieve the name I do like this on SIngleProduct.aspx:

```
object productRoute = Page.RouteData.Values["ProductName"];

        if (productRoute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productRoute.ToString()))
        {
// do stuff
}
```

If I very simple could just get the ID instead of name, it would be awesome.

Thanks a lot awesome-stackoveflowers ;-)

Comment: Can't figure out what you're asking ... it almost sounds like you want to exclude the product ID from your URL routes, but have it automagically appear in the route data.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. If you were to include an ID placeholder in the route, can you not retrieve it the same way?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: dbaseman: Correct, I want magic ;-) No, but seriously - some url rewriting trick should make it possible.
Tim Rogers: What do you mean? Don't you have to show it to the user then?

Comment: I mean have you tried a route such as `"legetoej/{Categoryname}/{SubCategoryname}/{ProductName}/{ProductId}"`?

Comment: Tim Rogers: Won't I have to show the ID to the user then?

Imran: Search engine optimization. I want to go for the "perfect" url :-)

Comment: So you don't want the Id in the URL, and you want to retrieve the Id of a product without accessing the database? And you're asking how this is possible? I think magic is the best option ;)

Comment: Ok, I will go for magic ;) Thanks. Nah, I just hoped there could be some magic tranfer option.
Thanks for it. Please post a solution telling I need magic, then I will accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the ID of the Product... take the ID and apply Encryption to it... something like DES or Triple DES, then apply Server.URLEncode method to the ID and then you can easlily hide the id.

When you open the Page you can simple take the encrypted ID and do a Server.URLDecode and the decrypt the ID.

Anyways... why dont you pass the ID of the product as a get Parameter ? Something like...
www.domain.com/product/myproduct?PID=#$$#12 , where the PID is encrypted and URL Encoded and then you can easily process it.