# what is best practice to hide table id from url?

Tags: database, jakarta-ee

I have a URL like the following.

http://www.mycompany.com/id?=2

The id part is incremental so people can guess what is next.
Is there a fancy way to hide table id from URL?
I know that I can encrypt it but isn't there a common api or something? especially, in Java.

thanks guys!

Jay

Comment: You need to add security, such as an ACL list. Obfuscation is a very pretty low-security measure.

Comment: Please take a look at this post as well - [hide url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614847/web-forms-and-url-rewriting-hide-id-show-name)

Answer (score 0):

use some kind of hashing algorithm in the database as a primary key instead of the ID (i.e. sha1(time + salt + random id), should be quite secure when it comes to guessing. Also implement a monitoring system for those who try non-existant salts with the possibility to block them ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm really interested in the monitoring part you mentioned. is there a name for the technique? I'd like to read about it.

Comment: I would suggest some relatively easy tool for log analysis (first thing that comes to mind is SEC (http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/man.html): if the content doesn't exist then add 404 error message to the header and with the correlator you can check: if more then 3 404-messages within 1 minute from the same IP then send alert/block IP.
Other possibility would be to do it on the application side (and just mark the non-existing queries to the session or to the database and if it makes too much queries to non-existant documents then next requests will not go through to the database).